# Увеличение области загрузки файла

Tags: jquery, javascript

Какой событие надо повесить на блок, что бы при переносе файла увеличивалась область загрузки, как это сделано на яндексе. http://c2n.me/iAaJ7q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dragOver

[Использование Drag&Drop в HTML 5](http://habrahabr.ru/post/187582/)